# How to pass custom arguments from the req object into a middleware function in express?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Trying to write a custom authorization middleware in express and running into some confusion about how to include custom arguments (instead of just the standards req, res, next).  The middleware will check if a user owns the resource by comparing their req.user.id to the userId attatched to the resource in question.

Basically I have this function:

```
function verifyUserAuthorization(roles, resource){
    return (req, res, next) => {
        try{
            //Checks if the logged in user is the owner of the resource by comparing req.user.id to resource.userId
            if(roles.includes('owner')){
                //Handles cases where the resource is an array and checks ownership of all resources in the array
                if(Array.isArray(req[resource])){
                    let allAuthorized;
                    for(let item of req[resource]){
                        if(req.user.id !== item.userId){
                            allAuthorized = false;
                            break;
                        } 
                    }
                    if(allAuthorized !== false){
                        return next();
                    }
                //Handles cases of a single resource
                }else if(req.user.id === req[resource].userId){
                    return next();
                }
            }
            //A 401 error is thrown by default unless a valid authorized role is found
            throw new Error("Access denied", {statusCode: 401});
        }catch(err){
            next(err);
        }
    }
};
```

And it must be called like this, using a string for accessing the req property where the resource is stored:

```
verifyUserAuthorization(['owner'], 'invoices')
```

But ideally I would like to be able to call it by passing the resource directly in like this, to make it easier to use on data that might be more nested. But of course when I refactor my middleware to use the new argument, "req" is understandable undefined.

```
verifyUserAuthorization(['owner'], req.invoices)
```

Are there any cool tricks to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `req` at the time you're calling the middleware factory. That doesn't exist until much later, when the handler processes a matching request. The best you can do at definition time is provide the name of the relevant property (`'invoices'`, as in your first example), or a function that can return the appropriate value given a request object (e.g. `(req) => req.invoices`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Thanks for the reply! I thought about using a call back function too, but in the end, if I'm thinking about it the right way, it will have the same problem I'm experiencing anyway. For example if on one call I want to pass req.page.invoices and on another req.invoices. I have it working, but it's sloppy as it needs logic for each possible place the data I want exists. Was just hoping there might be a clever trick I was missing. Thanks for confirming my suspicions though!

Comment: What's wrong with the way you have it written right now?  As you know, you don't have access to `req` when you call `verifyUserAuthorization()` so all you can do is pass the property name like you are already doing and then reference `req` inside the actual middleware function.  So, I don't understand what else you're hoping to do?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have some more complicated objects that are highly nested, the ideal would be able to pass those objects in, rather than write logic for how to access them all depending on what the string is. Not a huge deal, was just trying to come up with a way to have the function be slightly more dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a higher-order function that returns your middleware function, allowing you to pass the resource directly instead of just the string representing the property on the req object. It is worth to give something like this a try,

```js
function verifyUserAuthorization(roles, getResource) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const resource = getResource(req);

            // Checks if the logged-in user is the owner of the resource by comparing req.user.id to resource.userId
            if (roles.includes('owner')) {
                // Handles cases where the resource is an array and checks ownership of all resources in the array
                if (Array.isArray(resource)) {
                    let allAuthorized = true;
                    for (let item of resource) {
                        if (req.user.id !== item.userId) {
                            allAuthorized = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (allAuthorized) {
                        return next();
                    }
                // Handles cases of a single resource
                } else if (req.user.id === resource.userId) {
                    return next();
                }
            }
            // A 401 error is thrown by default unless a valid authorized role is found
            throw new Error("Access denied", { statusCode: 401 });
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    };
};
```

Then you can call this middleware like this,

```js
app.use(verifyUserAuthorization(['owner'], req => req.invoices));
```

This way, you pass a function to the verifyUserAuthorization middleware that extracts the resource from the req object, giving you flexibility in accessing nested properties.

Comment: Ah okay, now I am understanding the idea of using a callback function for this. Yes this will indeed accomplish what I was looking for. Thanks!